# Auto Crop image with angular

Tags: angular, image, crop

I want to crop images in my html page (to not lose resolution) with a specific width, i want to do that automatically (without input file) . So image should when loaded appears with the new dimensions (cropped).

this is my images :

```
<ng-container *ngIf="element.has_DA">
<ng-container  *ngFor="let daimage of element.default_action" >
    <a href="{{daimage.url}}" target="_blank" >
        <img mat-card-image class="image_card_icona_solixy_bot" 
                  [src]="element.image_url" alt="">
       </a>
</ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: what is the error you are facing?

Comment: I cannot crop these img html with Angular i would to get many images with specific width . En fact images have not the same dimension